# Trying to understand dependency injection

Tags: python-3.x, devops

I am trying to learn the concept of "dependency injection" in Python.  First, if anyone has a good reference, please point me at it.

As a project I took the use case of changing logic and formatting based on options passed to the linux command "mtr"

The dependency client class is MtrRun.  The initial dependency injection service is DefaultRgx (I plan to add a couple more).  The injection interface is MtrOptions.  And the injector class is just called Injector.

```
class MtrRun(MtrOptions):  # Dependency injection client
    def __init__(self, MtrOptions, options, out):
        self.MtrOptions = MtrOptions
        self.options = options
        self.out = out

    def mtr_options(self, options, out):
        return self.MtrOptions.mtr_options(options, out)
```

```
class DefaultRgx(MtrOptions):  # Dependency injection service
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = None

    def mtr_options(self, options, out): 
        pass  # code abbreviated for clarity
```

```
class MtrOptions():  # Dependency injection interface
    def __init__(self, svc):
        self.svc = svc

    def mtr_options(self, options, out):
        return self.svc.mtr_options(options, out)
```

```
class Injector():  # Dependency injection injector
    def inject(self):
        MtrOptions = MtrOptions(DefaultRgx())
        mtr_result = MtrRun(MtrOptions)
```

This snippet will not clear a lint.  My IDE claims that the MtrOptions class passed into the injection client and service are not defined.  When I try to resolve it, a new MtrOptions class is created, but the error persists.  I am certain I just don't know what I am doing.  Conceptually I admit a weak grasp.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the MtrOptions class passed into the injection client"? Do you mean ``MtrOptions`` in ``class MtrRun(MtrOptions)`` or in ``def __init__(self, MtrOptions, options, out):``? Is the order of code the same as in your real project, i.e. is ``MtrOptions`` defined *after* ``MtrRun``?

Comment: Note that there are several things that do not look right about your code. The name ``MtrOptions`` is used to refer to both the class *and* instances of it. ``DefaultRgx.__init__`` ignores its argument, always assigning ``None`` to its attribute. ``Injector.__init__`` stores values only as local names, not on the instance – these are thrown away at the end of ``__init__``. Also, it seems like ``MtrRun`` should not inherit from ``MtrOptions``, since it is already composed of one.

Comment: My understanding of what I am trying to do is pretty weak.  My understanding is that the `Injector()` will set the `DefaultRgx()` class as the dependency for `MtrRun()`.  At the end of the day, I want the `mtr_options` module in `DefaultRgx()` to be the one used.  `DefaultRgx()' is the service that will be injected if there are no options.  I statically set it to None, but it should only be selected if there are no options.  I am sure the inheritance is likely the problem, but I am not sure how it should look.  Do you have a good reference for dependency injection looks like in python?

Comment: For a great beginner level talk about multiple inheritance and dependency injection, I suggest watching Raymond Hettinger's talk, "Super considered super" from pycon 2015.

Comment: I watched his talk on YouTube!  Amazing!  Thank you so much Axe319!  I particularly liked the live examples.  I will rework my code and post it as soon as it lints correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I messed up several ways.  I did not understand the declarative way to establish inheritance.  Nothing in my example actually was an "object".  Second, order appears to matter.  The object classes seem to need to appear before their children.  Third, the injector class needs to include both sides of the classes to be injected.

```
class DefaultRgx(object):  # Dependency injection service
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = None

    def mtr_options(self, options, out): 
        mtr_result = ['Do stuff the old way']
        return mtr_result


class MtrRun(DefaultRgx):  # Dependency injection client
    def __init__(self, host, count, options):
        self.count = count
        self.host = host
        self.options = options

    def mtr_module(self, host, count, options):
        mtr_result = super().mtr_options(options, out)
        return mtr_result


class MtrOptions(DefaultRgx):  # Dependency injection interface
    def mtr_options(self, options, out):
        mtr_result = ['I was injected instead of DefaultRgx']
        return mtr_result


class Injector(MtrOptions, MtrRun):  # Dependency injection injector
    pass


def main():
    mtr = Injector(os.getenv('HOST'), os.getenv('COUNT'), None)
    mtr_result = mtr.mtr_module()
```

This linted correctly.  I have not run it yet, but conceptually that YouTube really helped things click.  Thank you so much.